# Estimate for integral of sine to the power of $-(1+a)$ where $a>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, estimation

I'm trying to solve or estimate this integral
$$
I=\int\limits_{\arcsin{k}}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{1}{(\sin{x})^{1+a}}\mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $0<k<1/2$ and $a>0$. The estimate should depend on $k$.

I have tried something like this: since
$$
\arcsin{k}\leq x\leq\pi/2\quad\Rightarrow\quad k\leq\sin{x}\leq 1 \quad\Rightarrow\quad 1\leq\dfrac{1}{\sin{x}}\leq\dfrac{1}{k}\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1\leq\dfrac{1}{(\sin{x})^{1+a}}\leq\dfrac{1}{k^{1+a}}
$$
we get
$$
I\leq\int\limits_{\arcsin{k}}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{1}{k^{1+a}}\mathrm{d}x\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}k^{-(1+a)}.
$$
But this is not good (or "sharp") enough. I need a better estimate or maybe some integration by parts. Any ideas for calculating the integral $I$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^{1+a} x}-\frac{1}{x^{1+a}},$$ 
and let $c=\arcsin k$. Then 
$$\int_c^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin^{1+a} x}dx=\int_c^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{x^{1+a}}\,dx+\int_c^{\pi/2} f(x)\,dx.$$
We can compute the first integral on the right explicitly. It remains to deal with the second.

The function $f(x)$ is reasonably well-behaved, since subtracting $\frac{1}{x^{1+a}}$ has taken the "badness" out of our original function when $k$ is small.  So the integral of $f(x)$ can be reliably approximated by one of the usual numerical methods, here applied *symbolically*. For instance we could use Simpson's Rule with $n=2$.

Comment: You are welcome. For high quality approximations. For functions like this one, and small $k$, the "taking out the badness" is a standard numerical analysis trick.